# Probability sampling exam question

Tags: probability, sampling

A fair coin is tossed repeatedly. Let $n > 1$. What is the probability that a
head will occur for the second time on the $n$th toss?

I have considered conditional probability, and got $\frac 12$, but the question is 6 marks and this seemed too straightforward.

I then considered sampling, and deduced that order doesn't matter and repetition is allowed, but wasn't sure if this was the correct way to go.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: For starters, if $n=2$, $p=1/4$.  The probability has to be a function of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 necessary components for the second heads to come up on the $n$th toss.  First, you have to have exactly 1 head come up in the first $n-1$ tosses.  Next, you have to have a head on the $n$th toss.  The probability of the second head on the $n$th toss is a product of these probabilities.  The second one clearly is 1/2.  What is the probability of the first requirement?

Comment: Is the probability of the first requirement (1/2)/(n-1)?

Comment: Think of all possible cases--here's one tttt....tht...ttt. How many cases? What's the probability of each one?

Comment: So it would be (0.5)(0.5)^n-1?

Comment: If $n-1 = 4$, one possible case is httt. Can you give me the others?

Comment: @Zain, not quite, because the 1st head can be in $n-1$ places.

Comment: That's what I meant by 'cases' @Paul. By the way, nice solution still giving Zain a chance to think.

Comment: So (0.5)(0.5)^n? Because if the head was in the first place, the probability would just be 0.5. That's my thinking and so (0.5)(0.5)^n simplifies to this taking n-1 cases.

Comment: You're getting closer. If $n-1=4$ what is each case, and what is the total probability?

Comment: The cases are httt, thtt, ttht and ttth. The total probability is 4(0.5)^4=0.25 so for n-1 cases would it be (n-1)(0.5)^n-1?

Comment: Nice! Extend to $n-1$.

Comment: @Arby just edited my comment to take into account n-1

Comment: So the answer to my original question would be (0.5)(n-1)(0.5)^n-1?

Comment: Perhaps. I think you have the tools now. Remember looking at cases, it really helps a lot of the time.